# The "to connector" does not work when using the the "algorithms" package bundle

Tags: algorithms

Suppose that one has the following pseudo code, written in LaTeX using the package `algorithms`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[t]
\caption{Euclid example}\label{euclid}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$ and foobar\label{foobar}
    \For{$i \gets 1$ to $n$}
    \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
    \State $a\gets b$
    \State $b\gets r$
    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
    \EndFor
    \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
    \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Written like that, it does work. However, when I try changing the like `\For{$i \gets 1$ to $n$}` to `\For{$i \gets 1$ \To $n$}` or `\For{$i \gets 1$ \TO $n$}` it then does not compile, with the error "Undefined control sequence". Still, according to the package's documentation, it should work (see page 5 of the official documentation at http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/algorithms/algorithms.pdf).

What am I doing wrong? How else could I get the `to` connector in a for-loop, so that the `to` appears in bold and in the same font as `loop` and `do`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`algpseudocode` is part of [`algorithmicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) and it does not provide `\To` or `\TO`. It's `algorithmic` (from the [`algorithms` bundle](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithms)) that provides `\To`.

Define your own `\To`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

\algnewcommand{\To}{{\normalfont\bfseries to }}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[t]
  \caption{Euclid example}\label{euclid}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d.\ of $a$ and $b$}
      \State $r\gets a \bmod b$ and foobar
      \For{$i \gets 1$ \To $n$}
        \While{$r \neq 0$}\Comment{We have the answer if $r$ is $0$}
          \State $a \gets b$
          \State $b \gets r$
          \State $r \gets a \bmod b$
        \EndWhile
      \EndFor
      \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The g.c.d.\ is $b$}
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```